# Proof of there are an infinite number of primes by using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, euclidean-algorithm

How can I show that there are an infinite number of primes by using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic?

Comment: There were two answers. Why vote to close? Once again "This question is missing context or other details". What is needed?

Answer (score 4):

You start by assuming the opposite. Let's say there are a finite amount of prime numbers, in fact, let's write them in a list.

$P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$, ... $P_n$

Note, this is a **complete** list.

Now let's form a new number $a$, by multiplying all of our prime numbers and adding $1$. According to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, every integer greater than $1$ is either prime or a unique factorization of primes. So let's try both of these possibilities.

**Possibility 1:** $a$ is prime. However, we previously wrote all the primes on our complete list, so this is a **contradiction**.

**Possibility 2:** $a$ is composite. However, if it is, it needs to be a unique factorization of the primes on our list. But, it **won't** divide $P_1$ exactly, $P_2$, $P_3$, or any $P_n$ for that matter. So it is a violation of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, and therefore a **contradiction**.

Because we get a contradiction when we assume there are finitely many primes, it must be the opposite, or there must be infinitely many primes.

Q.E.D

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wanted.

Comment: @D_S Why not ? Euclid's proof exactly uses the mentioned theorem. I upvoted this answer and I am surprised that it has received no upvotes, but the much more complicated approach received $2$.

Comment: We do not even need the unique factorization theorem, if we modify the proof a bit : Step 1 : Every integer $N>1$ is divisble by at least one prime. Proof : The set of integers $t>1$ with $t|N$ is not empty because of $N|N$. Let $p$ be the smallest element of this set. Then, $p$ must be a prime, otherwise there would be an integer $a$ with $1<a<p$ and $a|p$ implying $a|N$. But this contradicts the choice of $p$. Step 2 : Assume , $p_1,\cdots , p_k$ are all the primes. Then the number $p_1\cdot \ \cdots\ \cdot p_k+1$ is divisble by no prime contradicting the claim we get in Step $1$

Comment: I found this version of Euclids proof in a german algebra-book and it is my favorite way to show that there are infinite many primes.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic doesn't *feel* essential in this proof. I think we could transplant this proof to a ring that is not a unique factorization domain to show that it has infinitely many irreducible numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way
is by assuming that
there are only a finite number of primes
and deducing that
if all terms of the form
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{a(p)}$
are counted,
there are not enough of them.

I don't remember the details,
but it might go
something like this:

The number of integers
of the form
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{a(p)}$
which are less that $x$
are of the form
$\prod_{p \in P} p^{a(p)}
\le x$
or
$\sum_{p \in P} a(p)\ln p
\le \ln x$.

We certainly have
$a(p) \le \ln x/\ln p$.

The total number of possibilities
is certainly less than,
where $N$ is the number of primes,
$\prod_{p \in P}(\ln x)/(\ln p)
=(\ln x)^{N}\prod_{p \in P}1/(\ln p)
$.

However,
for every finite $N$,
$(\ln x)^{N}$ will be less than $x$
for large enough $x$.

So $N$ must be infinite.

I just did this off
the top of my head,
so I'm not completely sure that
it is correct,
but it seems OK to me.

Anyway,
there it is.